# Question about the multiple choice for the oneparchoices environment

Tags: exam

For multiple choice answers, `\choice` creates multiple choice answers formatted with a period, i.e. "A.  B.  C. etc." Is there a way to change this so that it is formatted like "(A)  (B)  (C)," with surrounding parenthesis? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can redefine the command `\choicelabel`, as explained in Section 4.9 (Customizing the numbers) of the documentation file `examdoc.pdf`, on pages 38-39.  To get what you want, you'd use the command

`\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{(\thechoice)}`